# Why HTML5 input[type="file"] FileList object is readonly?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

I wanted to create my own widget for uploading images to a server so apparently `input[type="file"]` was the way to go. However I also wanted some functionality:

1. Display images' thumbnails
2. Preview an image - displays image in larger scale
3. Remove an image from the collection of images that is waiting to be uploaded

Everything was fine until I stumbled on point 3. from the list above. It turns out that the `FileList` object of the `file input` is `readonly` and you can't do any modifications on it. Thus if I wanted to remove an image I would have to choose all images except this one and overwrite the existing collection of images. So I wanted to know why they made it to be readonly? Are there some security reasons? Thanks.

It seems that you can't do everything in javascript after all, as I was starting to have such observations (lol).

Comment: Well you can mark it as deleted in your own way and upload it using FormData and ignore that file when you are adding the files.

Comment: Yeah, I came across some workarounds but hey... I'm just curious

Comment: FileAccess has always been locked down. Why? read the specification and see if they mention why.

Comment: Okay so this turned out to be interesting because I `actually` did what you said and look what they say - `If the element is mutable, the user agent should allow the user to change the files on the list in other ways...` [link](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/forms.html#file-upload-state-(type=file))